# Adobe CQ5 Touch UI : how to set default value of checkbox in touch UI

Tags: user-interface, touch, adobe, aem

I have used out of the box feature of touch UI to search assets from DAM, In this process I have used few checkboxes also to enter the search criteria. I have my checkbox in /apps/dam/options/predicates/productlifecycle/XYZ...named as XYZ.

I have used many methods to set the default value...
checked             Boolean(Type)       true
defaultValue        Boolean(Type)       true
inputValue          Boolean(Type)       false
jcr:primaryType     Name                cq:Widget
jcr:title           String              XYZ
type                String              checkbox
xtype               String              selection

Is there any way to select one of the values from checkbox by default???

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a component template to set initial/default values?